# Is it possible to change the speed of an AC motor(drill press) without losing too much torque?

Tags: motor, ac

I have a drill press as in the image below, it runs from 110V AC 60Hz and has internal belt reduction. Unfortunately however for some materials and hole widths, I need it to go even slower than It's been built for. Is it possible to drive the motors  in such a way that I can slow it even more without losing significant torque?(for example on a lower frequency higher voltage )

I can build a custom inverter if necessary. I'd like to avoid mechanical modifications if possible.

[image: Drill Press]

Comment: A lower frequency usually means a lower voltage or magnetic saturation occurs (bad)

Comment: I might think about changing the pulleys.  Or a different drill press, my Delta has three pulleys... with an idler in the middle.  (I'm not sure idler is the right name.) Which gives rpm's from 250 to 3000.  Maybe a DC motor with enough torque???

Comment: Considering the options I think its just a bad idea. Any modification amongst the proposed would cost more than the drill itself, only to overstress the remaining original parts.. Should have bought the right one from start.

Comment: You might be able to fit a surplus DC treadmill motor to your Harbor Fright drill press. Brushed DC motor SCR speed controllers are pretty simple and IR compensation gives you decent torque at low speeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a single-phase induction motor.  Variable speed is done all the time with 3-phase induction motors for industrial applications.  The device that controls the speed is called a Variable Frequency Drive or VFD.  Like it sounds, a VFD varies the frequency of the AC that drives the motor, and the motor changes speed accordingly.

Look at some industrial supply places to see if you can find a VFD with single-phase in and out.  Once you get the hang of what's there, buy one from ebay so that you don't get the 100x markup of a new one.

Also note that a motor has to be over-built to some extent to handle a VFD running slower than its native line frequency.  Those that aren't over-built will still work, but they may overheat more easily because the internal fan doesn't work so well at lower speeds.

Comment: took a quick look and all I can find is single to three phase.Where I live even used ones cost double what I paid for the drill so.. :(

Comment: Central Machinery = Harbor Freight. The Harb and Overbuilt usually don't belong in the same sentence ...

Comment: hehe, mine is not the same brand.. I'm from Brazil and have one that looks exactly the same (Im quite sure they're all from China).. So yeah, def not overbuilt.

Comment: As it stands, this is not a good answer.  VFD's for single phase induction motors are VERY rare and usually they only work with certain types of single phase motors (permanent split capacitor and shaded pole).  So, even if @WesleyLee can find a single phase VFD, he hasn't given us enough information to tell whether it would actually work with the motor he has.

Comment: I ended up not finding any suitable VFD and have not been able to accomplish what I needed electrically..

Answer (score 1):

At lower speeds you probably want to increase torque, not just minimise losses.

Better to consider changing gearing - those pulleys are just components. But you can't afford to increase torque too far, the taper holding the chuck in place has its limitations too.