# Soft starter for AC motors

Tags: arduino, pwm, soft-starter

I want to build an AC motor soft start. The way I found is to regulate the voltage from 0 to 220 V (within 2 seconds) to eliminate the inrush current. I did it using Arduino to generate PWM to drive a TRIAC.

Is there any way to generate the required PWM signal automatically to drive the TRIAC without using Arduino or manual adjustable resistor?

Comment: Yes, but an MCU is the simplest and cheapest way to do so.

Comment: Have a look at this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161960/is-it-possible-to-change-the-speed-of-an-ac-motordrill-press-without-losing-to) on SE where the author recommends a *variable frequency drive* (VFD) to adjust the speed of the ac asynchronous motor. Not its voltage.

Comment: No motor will start from "0". The minimum start voltage is 40-50% from nominal, depends on load.

Comment: What does "generate the required PWM signal automatically" mean to you in this context? There's always going to be some electronics generating the signal. The control system might be a microcontroller using a timer, or it might be an analog(ish) circuit charging a capacitor, but what would make one more "automatic" than the other?

Comment: if you see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYUcXIhxL1I&ab_channel=Electronoobs he is using Arduino to change the pulse to operate the triac. I want to do the same but to operate a motor for 40% of voltage at the start and 100% after 2 seconds gradually so i can soft start the motor.